# In an ion-item with a checkbox, when you set it to wrap, how do you make the checkbox align on the top?

Tags: css, ionic4, word-wrap

I have an `ion-list`, and every item has an `ion-checkbox` and an `ion-label`. Kind of like a todo list. The problem is: I have the text on the `label` set to wrapping (`class="ion-text-wrap"`), but the alignment is not how I'd like it:

[image]

I'd like the checkbox to be aligned at the top, not in the middle. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Your best move it to treat both checkbox and label are flex children and use that model

Comment: @serraosays I actually already tried flexbox, and I just tried it again. Or, can you write an answer to show me how to do it?

Comment: check out my solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ion-item` is display flex through `item-native` css class. So you just have to select check-box and `align-self: start;` to display it at top:

```html
<ion-list class="checklist">
    <ion-item>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label class="ion-text-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet arcu mattis, auctor velit ut, suscipit lacus.</label>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
        <input type="checkbox">
        <label class="ion-text-wrap">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis sit amet arcu mattis, auctor velit ut, suscipit lacus.</label>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

with css:

```css
.checklist ion-item > input {
    align-self: start;
    margin-top: 0.3rem;
    margin-right: 0.3rem;
}
```

Will render:

[image]

Tested on ionic 4, also why don't you use `ion-checkbox`?

Hope it helps!

Comment: why don't you use ion-checkbox? -- I forgot to say that, but I did! (I'll edit the question.)

Comment: @ZeroWorks when I tried this, I had to adjust margin-top to 1 rem to get it aligned. Not sure if this is the best way. Although I like the answer.

Comment: Also wanted to add if you are using ion-checkbox then the only css property you need to add is height: -webkit-fill-available. The above properties didn't work for me in case of ion-checkbox

Comment: @yatinsingla, sure, I answered with html `checkbox` not ion-checkbox because OP didn't specified which, `ion-checkbox` has its own container so the approach would be different or even easier.

Comment: It does work with ion-checkbox, at least on ionic 5

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to solve this problem is to put a container around your `input` and `label` and use the `flexbox` layout model. Flexbox will automatically vertically align both the `input` and the `label` to the top of the container, and the `label`'s wrapped text will stay inside of the checkbox.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <input type="checkbox" name="val1" value="something">
  <label for="vehicle1"> I have a really long label that sits next to this checkbox and wraps around and around and around the box. Watch me go... </label>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
/* Set container with flex */
/* Children will automatically be aligned in a row */
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: 15px 30px;
  max-width: 500px;
}

label {
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Demo on Codepen: 
https://codepen.io/staypuftman/pen/mdJJWNq

Comment: Sorry, I was using `ion-label` and `ion-checkbox`.  I guess I'll just have uglier checkboxes (okay with me). Anyway, I'll try this later and mark it as the answer if it works.